# Are .NET Core projects referencing PCLs cross-platform?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a .NET Core (ASP.NET Core) project created using Visual Studio 2017 RC (MSBuild).

I also have an old F# project library (traditional .NET Framework Library) that compiles to a dll file. I want to use it in said ASP.NET Core project.

To do that, I added a project reference in the ASP.NET Core project, opened the namespace, and made a few function calls in my controllers; it works perfectly when running the ASP.NET Core server using ISS from VS.

**My question is, will this arrangement work if I want to deploy to linux (Ubuntu)? Or does using external PCLs/dlls from .NET Core instantly make it windows-only?**

Note that I didn't have to add .NET Framework as a target framework in my `csproj` (it's MSBuild Core), it just worked.

Answer (score 1):

Since your F# project targets the .NET Framework it will not run cross platform. If you modify your F# project to target the .NET Standard library it will. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YI4MurjfMn8) is a video by Immo Landwerth explaining how the .NET Standard Library works.

You should be able to just to reference the .NET standard library and not have to change anything. However the current version, which is 1.6, is missing a lot of API's from .NET Framework. This is fixed in 2.0. Infact since your using .NET Core 1.1 I think you are already using 2.0, but I'm not certain. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOzcVwzkGP0) is another video by Immo explaining how it should work.

That being said, I'm not sure what the F# support is like with .NET Standard.

Comment: Is that a characteristic of all DLL files? That is, what difference is there between a DLL generated using .NET Standard and one that is a PCL?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure, I myself am quite confused about this as well. I think I understand it for the most part, but some areas I'm still in the dark. I'll try to find an answer, but for the time being I can't provide a solid answer. Here's an in depth blog post by Immo that may help. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/ I think you want to look at the section 'As a library author, what should I do now?' Control-F and search for that.